# Silent Print of HTML url with desired printer name

Tags: printing, applet, silent, appletviewer

I need a script either in java applet or in any language for PHP to print silent printing the given URL in HTML to given Printer name with given no of copies. e.g http://myserver.com/printThis.php?url=http://anyserver/invoice/Invoice.html&printer=Dell&copy=2

If i run this URL in browser then it should print the given HTML (invoice) url  to given Printer without showing Print Dialogue box

**I need such script for HTML url not PDF url**

I have created a java applet for this , it runs fine from CMD using appletviewer but it can not run from Browser, giving error : Error occurred while trying to Read: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.oracle.com:80 connect,resolve)

If I need to signed or given somewhere permission then please let me know code or path details

Please help what was wrong

---

I have got jZebra ( http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/ ) for this but printing is not working to any printer , its allows to save pdf only for PDFCamp Printer but it also print blank to page :(

Has anybody successfully make working with jZebra ?

Comment: That would be great for dumping a dozen pages of special offer coupons for sex shops to the company printer!  That is why: 

1. You won't be able to do that. 
2. Even if you find a way, it is a security bug that will soon be fixed.

Comment: For web business module, after finalizing an order on web, its need to auto print invoice without poping print dialogue box. I searched on net, some are (paid) scripts which provide this only for PDF invoices and i want to directly print Html invoice instead converting to PDF invoice

Comment: @AndrewThompson What an excellent idea

Answer (score 0):

See [Signing and Verifying JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) in the tutorial.